# How to return the last row in a table when the primary key is null?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page with a tabular form in apex that returns a row from a table based on a hidden item called ROW_ID that the user enters. If the user does not enter a ROW_ID I would like the tabular form to return the last row in the table (the row with the highest ROW_ID).
I have a query like so which is the default value for ROW_ID

```
BEGIN
SELECT row_id into :P4_ROW_ID
FROM qa_swab_calendar
WHERE row_id = (SELECT max(row_id)
               FROM qa_swab_calendar)
and CREATION_DATE >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY');
END
```

The above query gives ROW_ID the value of the last row in the table which I want but the tabular form does not return any values. My question is how do I get the tabular form to return this last row?

Comment: Is this a timing issue?  i.e. does the code above run before or after the tabular form is rendered?

Comment: Yes, I've come to suspect it is. I'm very new to APEX and wasn't aware of ordering precedence. I'm working changing it but I do think this is the problem.

Comment: There is a utility to display the events in the order they occur - in APEX 4.2 this is Utilities > Page Events from the page builder.  It is available in other versions but may be accessed differently.

Comment: @HeathHackett Is `CREATION_DATE` really stored as a character string in your DB? If so you should convert it to a date for your comparison instead of changing sysdate to a string, especially since the `'DD-MON-YY'` format you are using does not sort in chronological order.  Also as currently written the query will only return records with a day of month >= todays day of month.  Today is the 12th so records created on the 13th, 14th, 15th, etc. of any month or year would match, but only if they have the current `max(row_id)`. If the max row_id's creation_date is the 1st, you get no records.